# Overloading Pointer objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

Hi 
how do I overload pointer objects . I tried it doesnt work out . can anyone help me.

```
CMyClass *InstancePtr = new CMyClass;
Myclassptr = MapObject->second; // returns *CMyclass
//overlaod Assignment operator ...
InstancePtr = Myclassptr;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

CMyClass * CMyClass::operator=(const CMyClass *ptr) 
{
    //some operation    
    int x = 4; 
    x = x - 2;

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overload operators for pointer type objects.

You can only overload an operator where at least one of the operands is of class type or enum type.

Since an overloaded assignment operator must be implemented as a non-static member function, it can only be overloaded where the left-hand side operand is of class type.

Comment: is there any work around .. I already have a myClass pointer for which I want to take 20 copies of it( not pointing to same address)  . any idea welcomed.

Comment: @ITion:  Presumably that pointer points to an object of type `MyClass`.  Have you considered dereferencing that pointer?